# Oracle sql result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written a query in Oracle SQL which returns the following result:

```
accountName1 null
null         hostName
accountName2 null
null         hostName
```

Instead I would like the result to look like that:

```
accountName1 hostName
accountName2 hostName
```

Comment: Without your current query, table structure and raw data, how do you expect us to be able to help you? Is the same `hostname` value actually always shown, or are they different?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that one or other column value will always be `NULL` then:

```
SELECT MAX( account_name ) AS account_name,
       MAX( host_name    ) AS host_name
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         NVL2(
           account_name,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NVL2( account_name, ROWNUM, NULL ) NULLS LAST ),
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY NVL2( host_name,    ROWNUM, NULL ) NULLS LAST )
         ) AS rn
  FROM   your_table t
)
GROUP BY rn;
```